# Netlogo working with specific items using nested lists

Tags: list, netlogo, sublist

All

I'm trying to simulate a 100 users (breed) each of them having users-own attributes which are tracked over various two runs of ticks say 0 & 1. I store these values as a list within a list and sorted them. They appear like this [[tick 0, user 2, attrib 1 ... attrib 9] [tick 1, user 2, attrib 1 ... attrib 9] [tick 0, user 3, attrib 1 ... attrib 9] [tick 1, user 3, attrib 1 ... attrib 9] ... [tick 0, user 99, attrib 1 ... attrib 9] [tick 1, user 99, attrib 1 ... attrib 9] ]

1. As I randomly 'ask users' to reassign certain attributes, how do I get the subset of matching values that matches the current user referred by 'who'? for example if the current user in context is 'user 3', how do I get the sublist of the matching entries from the list of lists?
2. Once I obtain the sublist matching 'user 3'[tick 0, user 3, attrib 1 ... attrib 9] [tick 1, user 3, attrib 1 ... attrib 9], how do I get the index of each line & the items within that list? for example if I need to access the last item on the sublist (corresponding to tick 1) so that I can obtain the value of attrib 9 to process it further?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It would be easier, to understand the context and to answer, if you could show a small reproducible version of your problem (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your list is structured: `[ [ TICK# TURTLE# ATT1 ... ATT9 ] ... ]`

```
[
  [ 0  0  1 .. 9 ]
  [ 0  1  1 .. 9 ]
  [ 0  2  1 .. 9 ]
  ...
  [ 0 99  1 .. 9 ]
  [ 1  0  1 .. 9 ]
  [ 1  1  1 .. 0 ]
  ... and so on ...
```

And the number of turtles is always CONSTANT

Then you can calculate the index of the item you need.

```
;; attribute data is in list "data"
LET total-turtles COUNT TURTLES
LET desired-tick 1   ;; number of the tick
LET desired-turtle 7 ;; WHO of turtle
LET desired-attribute 4 
;; calculate the sublist index
LET sublist-index desired-tick * total-turtles + desired-turtle
;; get the sublist
LET attribute-sublist ITEM sublist-index data
;; get the value from the sublist
LET attribute-value ITEM (desired-attribute + 2) attribute-sublist
```

If you set `desired-turtle` to `[WHO] OF ONE-OF TURTLES` you are working with a random turtle. Or you can `ASK` a random turtle to do the above, and it can just use its own `WHO`.

If you add the info to the list strictly in order, then you don't need to store the tick# or who#, and you don't need to sort it.

If you let the turtle store its own list of prior attributes, it might be even easier to store and access, depending on your application.

Now you have the pieces needed for a random turtle to access the history list and grab the values from its own history, or some other turtle's history.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestions. The [WHO] and sublist "ITEM" worked for me. I will try the other ones.